# Delay on all network activity on CentOS with DNS

Tags: linux, dns, centos

We have a CentOS 7 VM instance on ESXi that is exhibiting a delay every time network calls are made that require DNS resolution (for example "ping"). The DNS server is on a Windows server, and no other hosts on the network using the same DNS server have the problem so it seems isolated to something in CentOS.

The configuration for the network adapter is as follows:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=no
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=ens160
UUID=61c69ed9-a97b-40ea-a602-5fe82b9e79cc
DEVICE=ens160
ONBOOT=yes
PEERDNS=no
IPADDR=10.223.27.3
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=10.223.27.1
DNS1=10.223.27.2
DOMAIN=arndev.com
HWADDR=00:50:56:11:11:01
```

The DNS server is at IP address 10.223.27.2

If I "nslookup" one of the other hosts on the network it returns almost immediately:

```
$ time nslookup devtest1
Server:         10.223.27.2
Address:        10.223.27.2#53

Name:   devtest1.arndev.com
Address: 10.223.27.51


real    0m0.011s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.005s
```

If I "strace" a "ping" command, I see it resolve the IP address almost immediately as well, and then a delay where there are two additional calls made prior to the ping succeeding to reach the host.

Originally each of these two calls were taking 5 seconds before they timed out, making a 10 second delay in total. I did find an "options timeout:1" entry to add to "/etc/resolv.conf" that means I can reduce this to 2 seconds (2 x 1 second delay) which is obviously better, but in no way ideal.

The "/etc/resolv.conf" file is defined as follows:

```
options single-request-reopen
options timeout:1

search arndev.com
nameserver 10.223.27.2
```

If I ping just by the resolved IP address rather than the name, then there is no delay.

The command I am running for the "strace" of the "ping" command is as follows, and I have marked the location where the delay occurs in the output:

```
$ sudo strace -s 128 -t ping devtest1
PING devtest1.arndev.com (10.223.27.51) 56(84) bytes of data.

<-- delay occurs here, but it's already resolved the IP address -->

64 bytes from 10.223.27.51 (10.223.27.51): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.359 ms
64 bytes from 10.223.27.51 (10.223.27.51): icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.319 ms
64 bytes from 10.223.27.51 (10.223.27.51): icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.334 ms
64 bytes from 10.223.27.51 (10.223.27.51): icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=0.338 ms
```

I've marked where the delay occurs in the output below (towards the end):

```
08:09:41 execve("/bin/ping", ["ping", "devtest1"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
08:09:41 brk(NULL)                      = 0x55f55a5ea000
08:09:41 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3668e11000
08:09:41 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08:09:41 open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
08:09:41 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=37762, ...}) = 0
08:09:41 mmap(NULL, 37762, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3668e07000
08:09:41 close(3)                       = 0

< lines cut for brevity >

08:09:41 connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08:09:41 close(4)                       = 0
08:09:41 socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 4
08:09:41 connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08:09:41 close(4)                       = 0
08:09:41 open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
08:09:41 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1746, ...}) = 0
08:09:41 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3668e10000
08:09:41 read(4, "#\n# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# An example Name Service Switch config file. This file should be\n# sorted with the most-used services "..., 4096) = 1746
08:09:41 read(4, "", 4096)              = 0
08:09:41 close(4)                       = 0
08:09:41 munmap(0x7f3668e10000, 4096)   = 0
08:09:41 stat("/etc/resolv.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=113, ...}) = 0
08:09:41 open("/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
08:09:41 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9, ...}) = 0
08:09:41 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3668e10000
08:09:41 read(4, "multi on\n", 4096)    = 9
08:09:41 read(4, "", 4096)              = 0
08:09:41 close(4)                       = 0
08:09:41 munmap(0x7f3668e10000, 4096)   = 0
08:09:41 open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
08:09:41 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=113, ...}) = 0
08:09:41 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3668e10000
08:09:41 read(4, "options single-request-reopen\noptions single-request\noptions timeout:1\n\nsearch arndev.com\nnameserver 10.223.27.2\n", 4096) = 113
08:09:41 read(4, "", 4096)              = 0
08:09:41 close(4)                       = 0
08:09:41 munmap(0x7f3668e10000, 4096)   = 0
08:09:41 open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
08:09:41 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=37762, ...}) = 0
08:09:41 mmap(NULL, 37762, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x7f3668e07000
08:09:41 close(4)                       = 0
08:09:41 open("/lib64/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
08:09:41 read(4, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000!\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0x\350\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0008\0\7\0@\0!\0 \0\1\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0(\262\0\0\0\0\0\0(\262\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 \0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\6\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
08:09:41 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=61624, ...}) = 0
08:09:41 mmap(NULL, 2173016, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0) = 0x7f3660d14000
08:09:41 mprotect(0x7f3660d20000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
08:09:41 mmap(0x7f3660f1f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0xb000) = 0x7f3660f1f000
08:09:41 mmap(0x7f3660f21000, 22616, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3660f21000
08:09:41 close(4)                       = 0
08:09:41 mprotect(0x7f3660f1f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
08:09:41 munmap(0x7f3668e07000, 37762)  = 0
08:09:41 open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
08:09:41 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=305, ...}) = 0
08:09:41 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3668e10000
08:09:41 read(4, "127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4\n::1         localhost localhost.localdomain local"..., 4096) = 305
08:09:41 read(4, "", 4096)              = 0
08:09:41 close(4)                       = 0
08:09:41 munmap(0x7f3668e10000, 4096)   = 0
08:09:41 open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
08:09:41 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=37762, ...}) = 0
08:09:41 mmap(NULL, 37762, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x7f3668e07000
08:09:41 close(4)                       = 0
08:09:41 open("/lib64/libnss_dns.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
08:09:41 read(4, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \20\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0pr\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0008\0\7\0@\0!\0 \0\1\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\344N\0\0\0\0\0\0\344N\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 \0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\6\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
08:09:41 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=31408, ...}) = 0
08:09:41 mmap(NULL, 2121952, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0) = 0x7f3660b0d000
08:09:41 mprotect(0x7f3660b12000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
08:09:41 mmap(0x7f3660d12000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x5000) = 0x7f3660d12000
08:09:41 close(4)                       = 0
08:09:41 mprotect(0x7f3660d12000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
08:09:41 munmap(0x7f3668e07000, 37762)  = 0
08:09:41 socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
08:09:41 connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.223.27.2")}, 16) = 0
08:09:41 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
08:09:41 sendto(4, "\203\336\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\10devtest1\6arndev\3com\0\0\1\0\1", 37, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 37
08:09:41 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
08:09:41 ioctl(4, FIONREAD, [53])       = 0
08:09:41 recvfrom(4, "\203\336\205\200\0\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\10devtest1\6arndev\3com\0\0\1\0\1\300\f\0\1\0\1\0\0\16\20\0\4\n\337\0333", 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.223.27.2")}, [16]) = 53
08:09:41 close(4)                       = 0
08:09:41 socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
08:09:41 connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.223.27.51")}, 16) = 0
08:09:41 getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(37068), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.223.27.3")}, [16]) = 0
08:09:41 close(4)                       = 0
08:09:41 setsockopt(3, SOL_RAW, ICMP_FILTER, ~(1<<ICMP_ECHOREPLY|1<<ICMP_DEST_UNREACH|1<<ICMP_SOURCE_QUENCH|1<<ICMP_REDIRECT|1<<ICMP_TIME_EXCEEDED|1<<ICMP_PARAMETERPROB), 4) = 0
08:09:41 setsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IP_RECVERR, [1], 4) = 0
08:09:41 setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [324], 4) = 0
08:09:41 setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [65536], 4) = 0
08:09:41 getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [131072], [4]) = 0
08:09:41 fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
08:09:41 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3668e10000
08:09:41 write(1, "PING devtest1.arndev.com (10.223.27.51) 56(84) bytes of data.\n", 62) = 62
08:09:41 setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMP, [1], 4) = 0
08:09:41 setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 0
08:09:41 setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 0
08:09:41 getpid()                       = 16440
08:09:41 rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x55f559e15dd0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 0x7f3667aa6280}, NULL, 8) = 0
08:09:41 rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x55f559e15dd0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 0x7f3667aa6280}, NULL, 8) = 0
08:09:41 rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x55f559e15dc0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 0x7f3667aa6280}, NULL, 8) = 0
08:09:41 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
08:09:41 ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
08:09:41 ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=35, ws_col=142, ws_xpixel=1136, ws_ypixel=455}) = 0
08:09:41 sendto(3, "\10\0k0@8\0\1\265\373\222]\0\0\0\0Bj\3\0\0\0\0\0\20\21\22\23\24\25\26\27\30\31\32\33\34\35\36\37 !\"#$%&'()*+,-./01234567", 64, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.223.27.51")}, 16) = 64
08:09:41 recvmsg(3, {msg_name(16)={sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.223.27.51")}, msg_iov(1)=[{"E\0\0Tv\304\0\0\200\1w\361\n\337\0333\n\337\33\3\0\0s0@8\0\1\265\373\222]\0\0\0\0Bj\3\0\0\0\0\0\20\21\22\23\24\25\26\27\30\31\32\33\34\35\36\37 !\"#$%&'()*+,-./01234567", 192}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=32, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=0x1d /* SCM_??? */}], msg_flags=0}, 0) = 84
08:09:41 stat("/etc/resolv.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=113, ...}) = 0
08:09:41 open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
08:09:41 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=305, ...}) = 0
08:09:41 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3668e0f000
08:09:41 read(4, "127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4\n::1         localhost localhost.localdomain local"..., 4096) = 305
08:09:41 read(4, "", 4096)              = 0
08:09:41 close(4)                       = 0
08:09:41 munmap(0x7f3668e0f000, 4096)   = 0


                       <-- delay starts here -->

08:09:41 socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
08:09:41 connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.223.27.2")}, 16) = 0

08:09:41 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
08:09:41 sendto(4, "o\262\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\00251\00227\003223\00210\7in-addr\4arpa\0\0\f\0\1", 43, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 43
08:09:41 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)

08:09:42 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
08:09:42 sendto(4, "o\262\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\00251\00227\003223\00210\7in-addr\4arpa\0\0\f\0\1", 43, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 43
08:09:42 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)

08:09:43 close(4)                       = 0

                       <-- delay ends here -->


08:09:43 open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
08:09:43 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=37762, ...}) = 0
08:09:43 mmap(NULL, 37762, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x7f3668df7000
08:09:43 close(4)                       = 0
08:09:43 open("/lib64/libnss_myhostname.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
```

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this delay? If you need output from additional commands I'd be happy to supply...

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by creating a "Reverse Lookup Zone" on the Windows DNS Server that mapped to the same subnet.

As my IP addresses were 10.223.27.xxx the Reverse Lookup Zone was created (and automatically named) as "27.223.10.in-addr.arpa".

I believe this name matched the two socket calls that timed out in the "strace" command.

08:09:42 sendto(4, "o\262\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\00251\002**27**\003**223**\002**10**\7**in-addr**\4**arpa**\0\0\f\0\1", 43, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 43

The pings and other network related operations all now execute without any delay at all.